# Python MemoryError on a small forloop

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, out-of-memory

I'm having an issue with a fairly small for loop. I'm trying to create a list of some columns in an excel sheet and use the following code:

```
import string
col_list = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
for i in col_list:
    a = 'A' + i
    col_list.append(a)
print col_list
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File ".../table.py", line 5, in <module>
    a = 'A' + i
MemoryError
```

The output I want is a list that goes from ['A', 'B', 'C', ... , 'AX', 'AZ']

Could someone please help me understand what is going on here? Thank you.

Comment: Notice to anyone who wants to run this: this caused my Spyder to crash

Answer (score 6):

You are adding to the list as you loop over it, so the loop never ends.  Try making a copy of the list:

```
for i in list(col_list):
    a = 'A' + i
    col_list.append(a)
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't add elements to a `list` while you are iterating over it because it will cause your loop never terminated, instead you can use a list comprehension :

```
import string
['A' + i for i in string.ascii_uppercase]
```

also Note that there is no need to convert `string.ascii_uppercase` to a list since strings are iterable.

Comment: Your tring is missing an s. ;)